# matchQuery elasticsearch : How to search list of strings(wildcard) in elastic search using java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, wildcard

I am facing an issue when trying to search a list of strings over elastic search.

Below is the code snippet of how I am doing it:

```
QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("movies", Arrays.asList(("*"+list.getMovies().replace(",","*,*")+"*").split(","))));
```

But when using the above code without a wildcard, it's giving right results.

```
QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("movies", Arrays.asList(list.getMovies().split(","))
```

Though my requirement is to get results on every movie name with the wildcard.
I even tried wildCardQuery but it can not take more than 1 element at a time and I need to process the whole list on OR operator.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use **QueryBuilders.regexpQuery** instead and use `.*` instead of `*`.  But regexpQuery accepts String field_name and String regular_expression as parameter. So you will have to append .* to all the String values in the list and add each string in seperate regexpQuery.